# How do I exclude current object in ManyToMany query?

Tags: django, model, manytomanyfield

I have two basic models, Story and Category:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    ...

class Story(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    ...
```

And my view for story detail:

```
from django.views.generic import date_based, list_detail
from solo.apps.news.models import Story

def story_detail(request, slug, year, month, day):
"""
Displays story detail. If user is superuser, view will display 
unpublished story detail for previewing purposes.
"""
stories = None
if request.user.is_superuser:
    stories = Story.objects.all()
else:
    stories = Story.objects.live()
return date_based.object_detail(
    request,
    year=year,
    month=month,
    day=day,
    date_field='pub_date',
    slug=slug,
    queryset=stories,
    template_object_name = 'story',
)
```

On the view for a given story object -- I'm using a generic detail view -- I'd like to display a list of stories related to the current story via the categories applied to the current story.

Here's how I'm doing this currently in the story detail template:

```
{% for category in story.category.all %}
    <ul id="related_stories">
    {% for story in category.story_set.all|slice:"5" %}
        <li><a href="{{ story.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ story.headline }}">{{ story.headline }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

This provides me what I need except I'd like to avoid displaying the linked headline for the story I'm viewing currently.

I believe this is done via the "exclude" filter, but I'm not sure if this belongs on the Category or Story model as a method, or how to construct it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
class Story(models.Model):
...
   @property
   def related_story_set(self):
       category_id_list = self.category.values_list("id", flat=True)
       return Story.objects.filter(category__id__in=category_id_list).exclude(id=self.id)
```

Then you can do this in the template:

```
<ul id="related_stories">
{% for related_story in story.related_story_set.all|slice:"5" %}
    <li><a href="{{ related_story.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ related_story.headline }}">{{ related_story.headline }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, and with less code. What is `flat=True` doing in this case?

Comment: Ah, a problem: If you have two stories that belong to the same two (or more) categories, you'll get duplicate entries in the list. Any idea how you filter these out?

Comment: Actually, it appears if I call `distinct()` on the story object query, it filters out duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You could just check in the template if the currently iterated story is the original story:

```
{% for category in story.category.all %}
    <ul id="related_stories">
        {% for substory in category.story_set.all|slice:"5" %}
            {% if substory != story %}
                <li><a href="{{ substory.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ substory.headline }}">{{ story.headline }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

---

You asked to put it in a model method:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_categories_with_stories(self):
        categories = self.category.all()
        for category in categories:
            category.stories = category.story_set.exclude(id=self.id)[:5]
        return categories
```

This doesn't solve your expensive query issue, but that wasn't a part of the question.

```
{% for category in story.get_categories_with_stories %}
    <ul id="related_stories">
        {% for substory in category.stories %}
               <li><a href="{{ substory.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ substory.headline }}">{{ story.headline }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That works, but it feels like there's too much logic happening in the template. How can I move this to a method on the model (and which model)?

Comment: You're right, this is view logic, so it should go in your view (not model), but I will post an example.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Forgive me if this is an ignorant question, but how to I use this within the date-based generic detail view I have now? And then, how do I access this in the template?

Comment: Ah, thanks! Unfortunately, I don't understand how that snippet needs to go into the view, which I added to my code in my question. Could you adjust your example to show how this needs to look? Thanks! (I'm new to this.)

Comment: that snippet would be a model method on your story (you originally asked for that :) -- I personally think it belongs in the view. Updating with model example

Comment: Gotcha. Apologies for my confusion. This works for now. But I certainly agree about moving it to the view. Thanks very much for your help and patience!